# Invalid write of size 1 X bytes **inside** a block of size >X **alloc'd**

Tags: c, r, valgrind

I'm relatively new at debugging valgrind errors, and this one has me stumped:

```
==1920== Invalid write of size 1
==1920==    at 0x4C2ECC7: strcpy (/builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.11.0/memcheck/../shared/vg_replace_strmem.c:506)
==1920==    by 0x1D533B57: CSR_bullet (packages/tests-vg/vetr/src/cstringr.c:448)
            ... redacted (see end for full error)
==1920==  Address 0x1bd1be1f is 5,599 bytes inside a block of size 7,960 alloc'd
==1920==    at 0x4C2BBAD: malloc (/builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.11.0/coregrind/m_replacemalloc/vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==1920==    by 0x4F3D3E: GetNewPage (svn/R-devel/src/main/memory.c:879)
            ... redacted (see end for full error)
```

Notice this is **1** byte **well inside** an **alloc'd** block.  I've seen similar errors that involve writing after, or before, or into a free'd block, or even writes where the write size is greater than end of block - address (therefore overflowing), but I can't find one like this one.

This is happening on the [R CRAN check farm](https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/bdr/memtests/valgrind/vetr/tests/run.Rout.fail) at [this line of code](https://github.com/brodieG/vetr/blob/7a57be26d4a7141931426010c2d4b813c13ec054/src/cstringr.c#L448).

I cannot reproduce the error locally with valgrind on OSX or on a linux VM.

Beyond that, the error doesn't make sense to me.  Why can't I write 1 byte in the middle of the allocated block?  This is all running inside R, so it's possible I guess that the allocation in question was made by a different part of the program and it is somehow reserved (one possible hint that that's happening is that the allocations I requested from R were less than 60 bytes when the error shows up), but I don't know if that is something that valgrind would be able to detect anyway.

Full error:

```
==1920== Invalid write of size 1
==1920==    at 0x4C2ECC7: strcpy (/builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.11.0/memcheck/../shared/vg_replace_strmem.c:506)
==1920==    by 0x1D533B57: CSR_bullet (packages/tests-vg/vetr/src/cstringr.c:448)
==1920==    by 0x1D53317D: CSR_bullet_ext (packages/tests-vg/vetr/src/cstringr-ext.c:107)
==1920==    by 0x4852BD: do_dotcall (svn/R-devel/src/main/dotcode.c:1252)
==1920==    by 0x4C274D: Rf_eval (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:728)
==1920==    by 0x4C3AB5: R_execClosure (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:1617)
==1920==    by 0x4C2391: Rf_eval (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:747)
==1920==    by 0x4C29E0: forcePromise (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:520)
==1920==    by 0x4C27A1: Rf_eval (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:647)
==1920==    by 0x4C7746: do_withVisible (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:2998)
==1920==    by 0x4F7104: do_internal (svn/R-devel/src/main/names.c:1363)
==1920==    by 0x4B553B: bcEval (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:6503)
==1920==  Address 0x1bd1be1f is 5,599 bytes inside a block of size 7,960 alloc'd
==1920==    at 0x4C2BBAD: malloc (/builddir/build/BUILD/valgrind-3.11.0/coregrind/m_replacemalloc/vg_replace_malloc.c:299)
==1920==    by 0x4F3D3E: GetNewPage (svn/R-devel/src/main/memory.c:879)
==1920==    by 0x4F5814: Rf_allocVector3 (svn/R-devel/src/main/memory.c:2659)
==1920==    by 0x4CAEAF: Rf_allocVector (svn/R-devel/src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:247)
==1920==    by 0x4CAEAF: do_growconst (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:7490)
==1920==    by 0x4B64BD: bcEval (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:6483)
==1920==    by 0x4C2207: Rf_eval (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:624)
==1920==    by 0x4C3AB5: R_execClosure (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:1617)
==1920==    by 0x4BAE13: bcEval (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:6454)
==1920==    by 0x4C2207: Rf_eval (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:624)
==1920==    by 0x4C3AB5: R_execClosure (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:1617)
==1920==    by 0x4BAE13: bcEval (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:6454)
==1920==    by 0x4C2207: Rf_eval (svn/R-devel/src/main/eval.c:624)
```

Comment: there is probably a continuation of the message which tells when the block was deleted/freed.

Comment: Wouldn't it then say "... of size 7,960 free'd"?  The word "free" does not appear in the full output I link.

Comment: Maybe a (uncaught) previous error has overwritten a memory-control-block?

Comment: `... && *(string_copy + 1))` why do you suppress the final '\n' in the count of newlines? (besides the strange syntax: `... && string_copy[1])` is more common, IMHO )

Comment: `size_t i = 0; i < newlines; ++i)
size_all = CSR_add_szt(size_all, ctd_size);` You are performing multiplication by repetitive addition here. Are you afraid that a size_t overflows?

Comment: re: size_t that's the idea, however unlikely.  This isn't a performance critical part of the code so I was just trying to get in the habit.  Not the best way to do it either, but just learning right now.

Comment: re: last newline, because the newline count is to count how many padding characters I need to add before each line, and a terminating newline doesn't have a subsequent line that needs to be pre-padded.

Comment: And thanks for actually taking the time to look at the source.

Comment: Stack traces from full error are truncated by 12 entries (this is default). It would be helpful to see full untruncated stack traces with, say `--num-callers=100`.

Comment: That's useful to know; unfortunately since I don't have direct access to the machine where this happened, and I can't reproduce this on my mac or on a linux VM, I can't do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such error can happen when using memory pools.

Typically, a lib or an application (such as R) can build its own allocator
by getting big blocks e.g. from malloc, and then allocating small blocks
from these big blocks.
Valgrind has some client requests allowing to describe these blocks (big or inner smaller blocks), and their allocations.

With such client requests, you might have a part of a malloc allocated block
that is in fact marked as not addressable.

Seeing the stack trace entry :

> ==1920==    by 0x4F3D3E: GetNewPage (svn/R-devel/src/main/memory.c:879)

the above explanation looks plausible.

This then might be an indication that there is a real bug somewhere in R
and/or in the way the R allocator describes its memory pool to valgrind

Comment: This is indeed what is happening.  I was not able to reproduce this error myself because I was not running an instrumented build of R, but once I got my hands on one I was able to narrow in on the error.  I was indeed writing past the end of a small allocation from a shared page.